# Which tablets support 10+ finger multi-touch detection?

Tags: multi-touch, tablet

Do any of the Android tablets (such as the Motorola Xoom with Honeycomb) or the iPad 2 support detection of 10 or more finger multi-touch? I need that capability for an app idea.

Comment: 10+ finger touch? I really hope you're talking about multiple people using the same tablet.

Comment: I mean at least 10 (for all the fingers of one person), and possibly more -- I mean, if you can support 10, why not more, right?

Comment: Hell, why stop there, most of us have at least 10 toes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPad(1) does 11 fingers, i heard iPad2 does 10, prolly 11 aswell.
source: http://www.liewcf.com/ipad-tablet-multitouch-fingers-5202/

Android honeycomb also supports 10 fingers:
"Like the iPad, the Xoom will also have 10-finger touch capabilities"
source: http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/complete-impressions-of-the-motorola-xoom-tablet/

Edit: if you need even more fingers, you will have to develop for win7, 3m made a screen that officially supports 30 fingers, but the below article talks about detecting a whopping 50 points!
source: www.hexus.net/content/item.php?item=28401
but yea, thats just a stretch